# How can i make a rest api?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I want to make a rest api point with using the following part of the code

ProjectRepository.java

```
@CrossOrigin("http://localhost:4200")
public interface ProjectRepository extends JpaRepository<Project,Long> {

Page<Project> findByStateId(@RequestParam("id")Long id,Pageable pageable);
}
```

I have the following entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name="project")  
@Getter
@Setter
public class Project {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "state_id", nullable=false)
    private ProjectCategory state_id;

    @Column(name="project_engineer")
    private String projectEngineer;
```

}

This code doesnt compile. why? Bean problems it writes

Answer (score 0):

I have two questions regarding your details in the question.

1. Why are you putting @CrossOrigin (reference: https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/) in the repository ?
2. Can you post the error message along with traceback ? it would be much helpful to analyze the issue with those details

Comment: I use angular on the frontend and i found this solution online.
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerAdapter' defined in class path resource

Comment: Error creating bean with name 'mvcConversionService' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed

Comment: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'associationLinks' defined in class path resource

Comment: Here, I think the issue is with your spring boot project setup can you take a look into that once? precisely, check for the annotations on service layer. Normally this error has to do with improper use of annotations